# Доступ к серверу по внешнему IP через роутер

Tags: ip, роутер

Есть роутер DIR-300/A/C1 с самой последней прошивкой 1.0.20

В нем настроен DMZ на сервер (192.168.0.100).

Через локальный IP сервера доступ с других устройств локалки на сервер есть, а вот по внешнему адресу из локалки обратиться к серверу не получается (что-то висит и нет ответа), зато извне сервер доступен.

В предыдущем роутере DIR-400 была аналогичная проблема, но ее удалось решить прошивкой DD-WRT. Для текущего роутера не нашел неофициальных прошивок.

Может как-то можно настроить на роутере доступ к серверу из локалки по внешнему IP?

Подозреваю, что роутинг может помочь, но мало что в сетях понимаю и разбираться и изучать нет времени. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает.

Утилита traceroute роутера возвращает всего одну строку с внешним адресом.

Comment: Вообще обращаться к ресурсам сети по внешнему адресу не камельфо, это марсианские пакеты для рутера. То что вы хотите изначально не правильно, опишите начальную проблему, вам нужно другое решение.

Comment: На сервере есть апач и несколько сайтов на поддоменах.Иногда требуется зайти на эти сайты с мобилки, которая в той же локалке.На компе я могу в хостах прописать локальный IP для домена и поддоменов, а на мобилке нет такой возможности.

Comment: Пропишите в dns либо на рутере , либо сделайте локальный.

Comment: portforwarding для порта 80 с внешнего ИП на внутренний пробывали?

Comment: Не помогает проброс портов.

Comment: Значит, неправильно делаете! Опишите процедуру, плиз.Вообще-то это должно делаться на внешнем роутере, с конкретным IP адресом или именем, иначе куда же вы будете заходить? Но есть и ещё вариант - пробить VPN через Teamviewer или LogmeIn.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, мое мнение по данной проблеме:

1. Teamviewer нельзя использовать! Это брешь в Вашей защите. Что бы подключаться к Вашему серверу извне по этой схеме, необходимо что бы Teamviewer с сервера был ВСЕГДА включен (т.е. подключен к серверу подключений Teamviewer, который неизвестно кем и для чего может быть использован);
2. Правильное решение: VPN до Вашей локалки. Т.е. устанавливаем VPN соединение с рутером, получаем IP внутренней (за-роутерной сети) и спокойно работаем.